# Connecting R to MySQL - "Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"

Tags: mysql, r

```
library(RMySQL)
conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="root", dbname="myDB")
```

1) All other searches for this question keep suggesting that the MySQL server needs to be running but i've downloaded it and opened it up and it says the server is running
2) I'm not totally sure by default it creates username root and no password, but i guess this error trying various combinations. I have even tried typing in the initializing password that I set up when I downloaded MySQL.

I'm working on Mac OS X High Sierra.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is MySQL server running on local machine or remote machine? have you secured your mysql by changing root user/password?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)

conn=dbConnect(MySQL(),  user="", password="", dbname="", host="")
```